# what is the purpose of return 0 and return 1 and when to use

Tags: shell-script

I wanted to know when to make use of return 0 and return 1 in code block

can some one illustrate with an detail explanation

Comment: return 0 for success

Comment: start by looking at `test` and `if`.

Answer (score 2):

In Bash, you can return any value from a function, but it is truncated to 8 bits and becomes unsigned. When you examine it with $?, it will be in the range 0..255. If you do not use return to provide a status, the function returns the status of the last command executed within the function.

The same $? substitution mechanism is used to fetch status from external commands and from user functions. But, for external commands, there are additional reserved values. As it may not be obvious in a large script which calls are to shell functions and which are to to external commands, it is prudent to follow the same conventions, which are:

0: Success. If the shell -e option is enabled, returning a non-zero status will exit the script even if the command actually worked.

>128: The command was terminated by a signal, so could not return a completion status. The system provides a status of (128 + Signal Number).

127: The shell started a new process, but the command could not be found.

126: The shell started a new process, but the command found is not executable.

My reference for this is

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Exit-Status

Section 4.3.1 of the same document contains a description of set -e, which shows how Bash assigns special meaning to status zero. This is confirmed by the EXIT STATUS section of the man page for every command.

I don't see a code here for "Failed to fork": both 126 and 127 appear to be returned from the shell's own child process. fork() can definitely fail (returns -1, errno EAGAIN or ENOMEM), but what status Bash makes from that is not specified: clearly, if it failed, there is no child process to deal with it.

Experiments setting a maximum number of user processes, and launching a new bash, broke Bash, to the extent that it failed to respond when trying to read status.

```
Paul--) prlimit --nproc=400: bash
paul@paul-RV415-RV515 ~ $ export PS1='Limited--) '
Limited--) for j in {1..500}; do
> sleep 300 &
> Rc=$?
> (( Rc > 0 )) && { echo "${Rc}"; break; }
> done
[1] 5954
[2] 5955
....
[53] 6006
bash: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
bash: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
[54] 6007
[55] 6008
bash: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
....
[59] 6012
bash: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
bash: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
bash: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
Limited--) RC=$?

^C
^C^C
## Killed from another terminal.
```

Comment: will you illustrate with an example return 0 ,1 , 128 ,126 , 127

Comment: Added links to reference material. I came close to fork-bombing my own Laptop, so further experimentation there is out. You can easily run sleep 300 and send signals from another terminal, or set up test cases for grep, or write a script that returns a status passed to it as an arg. Grep is a good example where a valid result (no matches, perhaps looking for unwanted error messages) will terminate if set -e is active.

Answer (score 0):

0 means no errors. Any other value means something went wrong; even negative values can be returned.

AFAIK there is no other standard for return values except for 0. If you want to return a value that is not 0, it is up to you to tell the users of your program what different values/error codes mean.